# Program received signal SIGSEGV

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I wrote the following code:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<float> v;
    float pi=3.14;
    for(int i=0; i<25; i++){
        v.push_back(pi);
        pi*=1.1;
        //cout << v[i] << endl;
    }

    vector<float> w;
    float e=2.71;
    for(int i=0; i<25; i++){
        w.push_back(e);
        e*=1.1;
        //cout << w[i] << endl;
    }

    vector<float> s;
    for(int i=0; i<25; i++){
        s[i] = v[i] + w[i];
        cout << s[i] << endl;
    }
    getchar();
}
```

But my CodeLite informs me of an error:

> Program Received signal SIGSEGV. Stack trace is available in the 'Call
>   Stack' tab

Does anyone know what's going on? The code seems to be correct. There are only 3x25 numbers, so the memory should be sufficient. Please explain what happened.

Comment: `s[i] = v[i] + w[i];` invokes *undefined behavior* - you need to use `s.push_back(v[i] + w[i]);`

Comment: where do you allocate space for `s`? `s[i] = ...` assigns to a place where you do _not_ own. try `s.push_back(...)`

Comment: @UnholySheep you're right. now it works, thank you so much!

Comment: @UnholySheep: Why are you answering in the comments section?